# Consecutive SnackBar messages in Angular Material 2

Tags: angular-material2

Is there a way to queue snackbar messages following the material design spec

https://material.io/guidelines/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage

Right now if I call .open() multiple times the previous messages get overwritten immediately

> Consecutive snackbars
>
> There is only ever one snackbar displayed. When a second snackbar is triggered while the first is displayed, the first should start the contraction motion downwards before the second one animates upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think Material snackbars are designed to show only one instance at a time, as per the documentation. See https://material.io/guidelines/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage (Transient)

Comment: Right, I linked in the post the Material design spec.  Their demo shows if multiple messages are submitted they get queued up

Comment: sorry I used a completely wrong link, I just wanted to use the same link you used. So here, they are marking it as a "bad practice" to stack snackbars I think.